# How do I find out if my linux platform supports strong aliases?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, alias, abi

The GCC manual describes -`fabi-compat-version=n`, which is used to handle variations in C++ name mangling in the slightly variant C++ ABIs of GCC 3.4 to 9.2, and probably later. It has an important caveat:

> On targets that support strong aliases, G++ works around mangling changes by
>   creating an alias with the correct mangled name when defining a symbol with
>   an incorrect mangled name. This switch specifies which ABI version to use for
>   the alias.

However, it's not immediately obvious how you find out if your platform does support strong aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to find out is to write a small program that uses `__attribute__` to create an alias, and then use `nm` to see if the alias exists. Here's sample code, which is a variant on the classic "Hello, World" program:

```
/* strong_alias.c 
   compile with 'gcc strong_alias.c'
   run ./a.out to check it works, and then run 'nm ./a.out'
   to check that strong_alias() has the same address as main() */

#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf( "Hello, World\n");
  return 0;
}

int strong_alias( int argc, char *argv[]) __attribute__ (( alias ("main")));
```

Compile it and check that it runs, then use `nm strong_alias` to look at its symbol table. Here's a version that was compiled on CentOS 7 for x86-64:

```
nm ./a.out | egrep ' (main|strong_alias)'
000000000040052d T main
000000000040052d T strong_alias
```

We can see that `main` and `strong_alias` have the same address, and are thus aliases.

Comment: *＋1* for a thorough answer. But it is kind of crummy in that the proprocessor should be able to do this work, and not require something like Autotools to figure out.

Comment: @jww Autotools? Isn't it easier to do this kind of thing with the command line and an editor? That's how I did this: the only part that wasn't trivial was understanding the ```__attribute__``` syntax.

Comment: How would you distribute a program in source form and have it behave correctly on different platforms and compilers? Surely you are not asking a user do this sort of thing manually, and then set a define in `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: Ah, now I'm with you.